# brew install nginx libnginx-mod-rtmp Error: nginx: Invalid bottle tag symbol

Tags: nginx, homebrew

There is a problem installing nginx. Please help. I try run brew install nginx ,but display Invalid bottle tag symbol,I don't know.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

try to reinstall brew

```
  brew update-reset
```